# How to add a Contact Form to sent to email address

Tags: contact-us, contact-form

How to add a contact form to our contact page but finding it difficult to do so.

I can add the form via html and styling etc but getting it to send to an email address is where I'm having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google forms to create and share forms via email. please refer

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en